# Where are the classes(), fields() and methods() functions from M3 documented?

Tags: java, documentation, rascal

I would expect them to be documented here: http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Libraries/lang/java/m3/Core/Core.html, since that's the package you need to import to get them, but they're not there are searching the documentation for them doesn't result in much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are undocumented as of yet. Have a look at the (simple) code in the libraries. You can find them in the Rascal explorer as a library jar in lang/java/m3/Core.rsc, or online on github at https://github.com/cwi-swat/rascal/blob/master/src/org/rascalmpl/library/lang/java/m3/Core.rsc